# Form inside iframe with cross domain doesn't connect to Google Analytics

Tags: performance, iframe, google-analytics, cross-domain, google-tag-manager

I have this situation.

Inside https://www.toyota.it I have an iframe which connects to https://tfsi.toyota.it (you can see it a [this](https://www.toyota.it/#/box-iframe/https%3A%2F%2Ftfsi.toyota.it%2F/size=fullscreen) link), which we will call **Configurator page**.

Inside Configurator Page I have a form with a button. This form sends info via POST to a target URL, which is https://tfsi-calculator.toyota-fs.it/, that we will call **Calculator page**.

Both Configurator and Calculator pages have the same GTM container installed, which I use to connect them to a Google Analytics property.

The issue is that Google Analytics property seems to be properly connected to Calculator page, but it doesn't register any hit.

Instead, if I open Configurator page outside https://www.toyota.it iframe, simply opening the page from browser, everything works as expected and Google Analytics register sources, events etc. from both Configurator and Calculator pages.

Thinking it could be a **cross-domain issue**, I tried changing the target URL of the form to an older version of Calculator page which is still hosted on toyota.it domain, and I saw that hits were actually registered on Google Analytics property.

So, since it seemed to be a a cross-domain issue (the iframe which contains Configurator page is hosted on toyota.it website but the page called after clicking on button form, the Calculator page, is on toyota-fs.it domain), I followed [this Universal Analytics Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cross-domain) to configure Google Analytics connection the right way but it's still not working at all.

Since both Configurator and Calculator pages are connected to the same GTM Container, I first tried the following code:

```html
gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', {
  'linker': {
      'domains': ['toyota-fs.it'],
      'decorate_forms': true,
      'accept_incoming': true
    }
});
```

And then I tried the following (and this is the one it's still in use):

```html
gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', {
  'linker': {
      'domains': ['toyota-fs.it', 'toyota.it'],
      'decorate_forms': true     
    }
});
```

But nothing changed.

Do you have any idea of how I could make it work?